# BASH - create and populate directories based on variable

Tags: linux, bash, loops

I am writing a BASH script that loops through the contents of a list file, pt2.lst, running a Perl script and saving the output with a filename that is based on the contents of pt2.lst. The following code works:

```
while read p; do
        perl Collect_Vaf.pl $1 $p > "$p_vaf.lst"
done < pt2.lst
```

...but only because the Perl script uses the second command line argument to name a file it prints to. Running the script above as "perl Collect_Vaf.pl $1 $p" would also work in this case.

Instead of saving the files in the same directory the script is run from, I would like to create new directories with names based on the contents of pt2.lst. I thought this would work:

```
while read p; do
        STR = "Sample_$p"
        mkdir $STR
        perl Collect_Vaf.pl $1 $p > "$STR/$p_vaf.lst"
done < pt2.lst
```

But this gives me the following three error messages for each iteration of the loop:

```
Vaf_Plotter.sh: line 11: STR: command not found
usage: mkdir [-pv] [-m mode] directory ...
Vaf_Plotter.sh: line 13: /.lst: Permission denied
```

**How can I create directories based on a variable then save files to those directories all within a loop?**

Here are a list of details that may or may not be relevant:

1. The file, pt2.lst, is generated with the bash script. Each line contains a 4-5 digit number
2. I intend to save several files to each newly-created directory by running multiple scripts within the loop; I've included only one for simplicity
3. The BASH script is run with a single required argument, $1, that serves as an input file for many of the script's commands

Comment: No spaces in assignments: `STR="Sample_$p"`; `_` is a valid identifier character, `$p_vaf` is not a variable, use `${p}_vaf` or `$p\_vaf` or `"$p"_vaf` or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the spaces around the assignment operator. That is, instead of this:

> ```
> STR = "Sample_$p"
> ```

You must write like this:

```
STR="Sample_$p"
```

Another issue is here:

> ```
> perl Collect_Vaf.pl $1 $p > "$STR/$p_vaf.lst"
> ```

Should be:

```
perl Collect_Vaf.pl $1 $p > "$STR/${p}_vaf.lst"
```

Because, according to your error message, there is no variable named `$p_vaf`. This also means that when you described your first example as "it works", most certainly that isn't true.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I didn't realize spaces count when defining variables. I assure you, however, that the first block of code I posted most certainly does work. It produces one file for each line in pt2.lst containing the output from the Perl script. I'm not sure why its working for me given your excellent point that $p_vaf is not a defined variable; but it most definitely works. I'll include version info in my question in case it helps shed light on this oddity

Comment: I just figured it out: the reason my first example worked was because the Perl script wrote to a file that was named based on the second command line argument, $p.